# Replacement for sun.text.Normalizer getclass(char a) in java.text.Normalizer getclass()

Tags: java

I am trying to migrate from java 5 to java 6.
We were initially using method `getClass(char a)` from `sun.text.Normalizer`
Need help with implementing the same in Java 6 using `java.text.Normalizer`

What could be the appropriate replacement for the below sample code ?

```
private int getClass(char c) {
    return Normalizer.getClass(c);
}


if(getClass(input.charAt(1)) ==
            getClass(input.charAt(0)){
}
```